# Mobile Futon on android not working, why?

Tags: android, couchdb

This is the actual error message i'm getting if i run it on an android phone. 
 I downloaded the source from the following place https://github.com/daleharvey/Android-MobileFuton

```
{"error":"bad_otp_release","reason":"To open the database `mobilefuton`, Apache CouchDB must be built with Erlang OTP R13B04 or higher."}
```

This is the same error i got when running on an emulator also. Can someone tell me what the issue is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've only been able to run MobileFuton Android on a tablet running the Honeycomb OS (we downloaded it from the app store, and didn't compile from source). The version in the Android app store doesn't run on Android ICS (I don't think it even shows up if you're running that version).

Try a different OS in your emulator and see if that changes things. You may need to update the source to get it to run on Android ICS. I don't think it's been updated for a little while.

Comment: Ah, thanks. You mentioned that i might have to update the source to get it to work on ICS. Can you tell me where i can find the latest source which might be working?
I really need to use couchbase/couchdb especially its ability to sync, desparately!

Comment: Actually some of the forked projects in that seem to work better!